# How to make the grid responsive on the mobile version. Using JS buttons

Tags: javascript, slider

I have a grid block. I need to make a slider on the mobile version in the manner shown in the picture. What is the most correct way to implement a slider with JavaScript?[open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZosH.png)

```
<div class="carousel_grid">
    <div class="div1">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div4">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div5">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div6">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div7">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.carousel_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  
}
.carousel_grid div {
  color: #313131;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 110%;
   

}

.carousel_grid

.div1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
.div2 { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
.div3 { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 3 / 4; }
.div4 { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; }
.div5 { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3; }
.div6 { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2; }
.div7 { grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 4; }
```

I use media queries to narrow the grid size down to one block, creating a block with a slider that defaults to display: none. and using js selectors I load the necessary blocks